# Wordpress WP_Query $args, show published posts AND the current user's pending posts

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, posts, args

On my Wordpress website users can write their own posts on the group wall. I want to display all published posts on the group wall. I also want to display pending posts to the current user who is the author of these posts. Right now when the user submits a new post, there is no information displayed about it, they may not know if their post got submitted. I want to show them their pending post with the information that they need to wait for the post review.

Is there a way to add the logic to the `$args` of the `WP_Query`? This is my code right now:

```
    //number of posts per page default
    $num =5;
    //page number
    $paged = $_POST['page'] + 1;
    
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $uid = $current_user->ID;
    
    //args
    $meta_query = array();
    $meta_query[] = array('key' => 'pm_accessible_groups','value' => sprintf(':"%s";',1),'compare' => 'like');
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'pg_groupwalls',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' =>$num,
        'meta_query' => $meta_query,
        'paged'=>$paged
    );
    
    
    
    //query
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    //check
    if ($query->have_posts()):
        //loop
        while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
```

And later I have my template. This way it is only showing published posts as of now. I tried to find some information about it here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/ , and later I tried changing the `$args` array to something like this:

```
    //number of posts per page default
    $num =5;
    //page number
    $paged = $_POST['page'] + 1;
    
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $uid = $current_user->ID;
    
    //args
    $meta_query = array();
    $meta_query[] = array('key' => 'pm_accessible_groups','value' => sprintf(':"%s";',1),'compare' => 'like');
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'pg_groupwalls',
        'post_status' => array (
             'relation' => 'AND',
             array(
                  'post_status' => 'publish',
             ),
             array(
                  'post_status' => 'pending',
                  'author' => $uid,
             ),
        ),
        'posts_per_page' =>$num,
        'meta_query' => $meta_query,
        'paged'=>$paged
    );
    
    
    
    //query
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    //check
    if ($query->have_posts()):
        //loop
        while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
```

It is most probably not the way to do this, and obviously, it does not work the way I want. It shows both published and pending posts to all users (not just the current user who is an author). I could maybe create a new WP_Query, but this one is already paginated and showing 5 posts per page with a "Load More" button, I don't want to break the pagination.

Is there a way to create this logic using `$args` array? Or any other way to achieve what I want?
Thank you in advance.

If there is more information needed or more of the code, I will try to update it.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
//number of posts per page default
$num = 5;

//page number
$paged = $_POST['page'] + 1;

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$uid          = $current_user->ID;

//args
$meta_query   = array();
$meta_query[] = array(
    'key'     => 'pm_accessible_groups',
    'value'   => sprintf(':"%s";',1),
    'compare' => 'like'
);
```

**For all publish post.**

```
$publish_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'pg_groupwalls',
    'post_status'    => array( 'publish' ),
    'posts_per_page' => $num,
    'meta_query'     => $meta_query,
    'paged'          => $paged
);

//query
$publish_posts = new WP_Query( $publish_args );

//check
if ( $publish_posts->have_posts() ):
    //loop
    while ($publish_posts->have_posts()): $publish_posts->the_post();

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
```

**For all pending posts of current user.**

```
$pending_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'pg_groupwalls',
    'post_status'    => array( 'pending' ),
    'post_author'    => $uid,
    'posts_per_page' => $num,
    'meta_query'     => $meta_query,
    'paged'          => $paged
);

//query
$pending_posts = new WP_Query( $pending_args );

//check
if ( $pending_posts->have_posts() ):
    //loop
    while ($pending_posts->have_posts()): $pending_posts->the_post();

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but won't this be showing only the posts of the current user? I want to show published posts of all users, but also pending posts only from the current user.